# "A friend of one" vs "a friend of one's"

Tags: grammar, possessives

Tell me please of there is any difference between the following sentences?

> A friend of Kate came over for my birthday party.
>
> A friend of Kate'**s** came over for my birthday party.

Are both sentence correct? If so, is there the smallest difference in meaning?

Answer (score 2):

They are both correct, and there is only a slight difference in meaning. You could read more into it than intended, but for the most part, they would be understood the same way.

- "A friend of Kate" means someone who is a friend **to** Kate.
- "A friend of Kate's" uses the possessive, so is someone Kate regards as a friend.

Assuming that the friendship is two-way, they both mean the same thing. :)